# Axios GET doesnt show me all datas. I need to make a second call to get them

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I've a vue component with a table on it

```html
<v-client-table
            ref="table"
            :data="artists"
            :columns="columnsDatatable"
            :options="optionsDatatable"
            @row-click="rowDetail"
        >
            <!-- ID -->
            <template v-slot:id="props">
                <small>#{{ props.row.id }}</small>
            </template>

            <!-- Fullname -->
            <template v-slot:fullname="props">
                {{ props.row.lastname }} {{ props.row.name }}
            </template>
        </v-client-table>
```

It gets the data from a Vuex mutation called during the mounted()

```js
mounted() {
        this.fetchArtists();
    }
```

When I store the data into the dBase and update the vuex array artists, the table shows just part of them. To solve the problem I have to reload the page, let the component make the axios get again and finally see all data I need.
I wonder why it happend
Any ideas?

**Here the fetch action**

```js
async fetchArtists({commit}) {
             axios.get(config.backend + "/artists")
                .then(res => {
                    commit("SET_ARTISTS", res.data.data);
                    console.log("mounted", res.data.data);
                }) 
                .catch();
        },
```

**and here the saveArtist action**

```js
async saveArtist({ state, dispatch, commit }, [artist, contacts, address, certificates]) {
            
            // Save
            await axios.post(config.backend + "/artists", artist)
                .then(res => {
                
                    let id = res.data.data.id;
                    
                    contacts.contactable_id = address.addressable_id = certificates.certificatable_id = id;
                    contacts.contactable_type = address.addressable_type = certificates.certificatable_type = 'App\\Models\\Artist';

                    if (!!contacts.first_email) {
                        axios.post(config.backend + "/contacts", contacts)
                            .then(res => console.log(res))
                            .catch(err => console.log(err));
                    }
                    
                    if (!!address.address) {
                    axios.post(config.backend + "/addresses", address)
                        .then(res => console.log(res))
                        .catch(err => console.log(err));    
                    }
                    
                    let fullArtist = artist;
                    fullArtist.contact = contacts;
                    fullArtist.map = address;

                    commit('PUSH_TO_ARTISTS', fullArtist);
                    
                    commit('common/SET_ALERT_TITLE', 'CREATED', { root: true });
                    commit('common/SET_ALERT_MESSAGE', 'Artist has been created!', { root: true });
                    commit('common/SET_ALERT_COLOR', 'success', { root: true });
                })
                .catch(err => console.log(err));
        },
```

Comment: Use Vue DevTools to check if all data is inside the Vuex store after you fetch the artists. If it is - you probably have an issue with reactivity, either in the Vuex getter or in the Vue component. If only part of the data is in the Vuex store - then your issue is probably on the backend.

Comment: IVO GELOV after the first axios call the data are partially on the store. They goes fully there ONLY if i refresh the page. I've checked my backend answer by postman and i get all data i expect

Comment: What does your `PUSH_TO_ARTISTS` mutation do?

Comment: IF the data is partially in the store - then either `console.log("mounted", res.data.data);` will show only part of the data (and then the issue is in the API) or it will show all the data and then the issue is inside the `SET_ARTISTS` mutation.

Comment: @Phil A simple push to array of artists:  PUSH_TO_ARTISTS(state, payload) {state.artists.push(payload)}